# Как ускорить запуск программы, собранной Pyinstaller'ом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

Собрал проект с помощью Pyinstaller, и в итоге программа запускается по 20 секунд, а то и дольше. Как можно ускорить загрузку?

Comment: Никак. Собранная с помощью Pyinstaller программа - это архив, в котором лежит интерпретатор Python, байткод вашей программы, все дополнительные библиотеки и ресурсы. При каждом запуске это хозяйство распаковывается во временную папку, и ваш код запускается интерпретатором. Ускорить запуск можно разве что если не собирать все в один exe файл - тогда и не будет этапа распаковки.

Comment: странно, 20 секунд это много. Что делает ваша программа, какие модули вы импортируете? Покажите ваши импорты. А сколько времени запускается ваш модуль `main.py`

Comment: Еще антивирус можно попробовать отключить, из-за антивируса тоже может тормозить.

Comment: Как вариант не собирать одним файлом, будет чуть быстрее на распаковке. В spec файле прописать пакеты которые надо игнорировать но не уверен что это будет заметно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На просторах YouTube'а появилось решение моей проблемы
https://youtu.be/lEAjwY5TAsE
Как раз таки через интерпретатор pypy, который предлагали для ускорения

Answer (score 0):

используй ускоренный интерпретатор pypy https://www.pypy.org/download.html

Comment: Я что-то не очень уверен, что pypy поддерживает упаковку с помощью pyinstaller. Вы пробовали это делать?

Comment: а обязательно это делать с помощью pyinstaller?

Comment: @Sheud_z вопрос был как ускорить запуск (уменьшить время старта) программы на python, упакованной pyinstaller-ом (подразумевается, что в один исполняемый файл). pypy сам по себе это точно не умеет делать. Возможно pypy поддерживает pyinstaller, это нужно уточнять. Но в любом случае это возможно ускорит работу программы, но вряд ли уменьшит время запуска.